# Why is translateY is always going in one direction

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="one">
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>

.one {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  background: #eee;
}
.two {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #999;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; // you can change it to top: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

Even if I'll change the bottom to top, the translateY will still move in the same direction for me(down), while when changing the left to right, for example, the translateX does change it direction.

Is this something related to my environment or is this is the expected thing to happen? If it is, is there a way to change the direction without using negative number in the tranlsate?

Please, don't suggest to use negative values. I'm aware of them and this question isn't about it.

Comment: `translateY` repositions elements along the Y axis - positive values to move down the Y axis, negative values to move up. `top` or `bottom` values have no bearing on this property other than the *initial starting position of the element before it is transformed*.

Comment: @mtthwmsn if so, why manipulating the same thing, just with translateX and right-left accordingly does have effect on it?

Comment: `translateX` is the same, `left` and `right` values have no bearing on the property.

Comment: @lawumaro - I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean, but setting a `left` or `right` property will not have an effect on `translateX` other than it's starting position. See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/6r94bhrx/

Comment: Can you post a piece of code that actually demonstrates this issue?

Comment: translateY is completely different from using absolute positioning (eg. top, bottom).

Comment: Oh, I can't believe nobody thought of this. _Which browser, on which platform?_